# Function called inside a component doesn't have updated props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a reproducible exam of my problem, I don't understand why after the `setDefaultValue` is called and the component is updated (you can see it's updated using the result of my console.log) If now I click on the reset button instead of the new `defaultValue` I see the old one.
Here is a link to the example showing this problem, I'll also paste the code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-tree-wtsgb4?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

import {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import TextBox from './TextBox';

export default function App() {
  const textboxAPI = useRef(null)
  const [defaultValue ,setDefaultValue] = useState('First')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>To reproduce please first click on the default value button then on the reset button</div>

      <TextBox getAPI={(api) => textboxAPI.current = api} defaultValue={defaultValue}/>
      <button onClick={() => setDefaultValue('second')}>1- Click me to change default value to "second"</button>
      <button onClick={() => textboxAPI.current.reset()}>2- Click me to call reset inside Textbox</button>
    </div>
  );
}

import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const TextBox = ({defaultValue, getAPI}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue || '')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (getAPI) {
      getAPI({
        reset: reset,
      })
    }
  }, [])

  const reset = () => {
    console.log('TextBox Reset DefaultValue', defaultValue)
    setValue(defaultValue)
  }

  console.log('TextBox DefaultValue', defaultValue)

  return <div>{value}</div>
}

export default TextBox;
```

To reproduce the problem:
1- Click on the first button to set a new `defaultValue`, see the console.log, you can see the `defaultValue` has changed inside the `TextBox` Component
2- Click the reset button, it calls the reset function inside `TextBox` but the default value logged there has the previous value!

Comment: Exporting functions like that is done using a hook. Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-buck-ljd0oc?file=/src/useTextBox.js

Comment: Please do not pursue your current approach, it's not necessary and error-prone.

Comment: @ChrisG I see so I have to export the function to make it work, Is there any other way to make this work without exporting and simply using a call back such as getAPI?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm developing my own Form and I want it to be uncontrolled and this is just part of the logic i came up with to improve performance and avoid rerenders in the Form component.

Comment: But this is specifically why hooks exists: so you can have arbitrary logic accessible from outside, exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisG What if the component is a class component? how can export the function inside that (please note the function calls a setState), can you add this to your example as well, Thank you.

Comment: With class components the usual approach is to lift the state up to the parent and simply pass it down.

Answer (score 1):

Here you save in *textboxAPI.current* function *reset* but just one time after first render of TextBox component. Function *reset* has a *defaultValue* in a **closure** and its value is 'First' during first render. So each next time you call *textboxAPI.current.reset()*, you call the *reset* function with *defaultValue==='First'* in its closure.

But you parent component controls child state and React does not recommend to manage your logic like that.

[UPDATED]
That will fix your issue, but **I don not recommend to organize a state logic like that**:

```js
const TextBox = ({defaultValue, getAPI}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue || '')

  const reset = () => {
    console.log('TextBox Reset DefaultValue', defaultValue)
    setValue(defaultValue)
  }


  if (getAPI) {
    getAPI({
      reset: reset,
    })
  }

  console.log('TextBox DefaultValue', defaultValue)

  return <div>{value}</div>
}

export default TextBox;
```

Comment: How can i fix this so its value is not fixed? Also I'm writing my own Form and this is just part of the logic that's why the way I'm doing this might seem weird.

Comment: add update in my reply. But I would really recommend to re-design your Form

Comment: Thank you, yes if calling `getAPI` inside the render is the only way then it's really messy and I probably will avoid it as well, I guess the hook solution mentioned by @ChrisG in the comments is the way to go.

Comment: hope to answer your init question, good luck=)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I learned from the comments I tried using `Hooks` but There were too many changes needed especially I had some issues with `React.lazy` so I tried to look for more solutions until I found that using a combination of `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle` I can export my `reset` function without changing my current structure and it works as it should, I thought that I should share my solution for anyone else who might be looking for an alternative solution to `Hooks`.